Cant create username in Phantomo wallet
Recently I want to create a username in Phantom Wallet. However, I receive an error message as attached. 
Anyone know how to resolve this issue?
I have tried:

Using PC Phantom extension
Uninstall and reinstall app

So far, none seems to work

I’m voting to close this question because this site is not meant for wallet support
